# Find starting index & length of longest run in array ? C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

For the given array

```
int arr[0] = {0,1,0,0,0};
```

I need to return the starting index of the longest run of 0's

So in this case

`findIndex(arr)`

would return another array `result = {2,3}`. 2 represents the starting index of the run and 3 represents the length of the run.

Here's my attempt which can only find the length but not the index

```
int findLongestConseqSubseq(int arr[], int n)
{
int max = 1;
int current = 1;
int i;

for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (arr[i - 1] == arr[i])
    {    /* the run continues */
        current++;
        max = current > max ? current : max;
    }
    else
    {    /* the run was broken */
        current = 1;
    }
}
return max; 
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can just update the index whenever you update the maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of saving just the `max`, save the index as well.Instead of returning the longest length of `0`s from `findLongestConseqSubseq()`, you could return a `pair<int,int>` where first element would represent the index and second element would represent the max length.

```
pair<int,int> findLongestConseqSubseq(int arr[], int n)
{
pair<int,int> max; //starting index, length
max.second = 1;
max.first=0;

pair<int,int> current;
current.second = 1;
current.first=0;
int i;

for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == arr[i-1])
    {    /* the run continues */
        current.second++;
        if (current.second > max.second) 
        {
            max.second = current.second;
            max.first = current.first;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        current.second=1;
        current.first=i;
    }
}
return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two variable `curr_index` & `max_index` to store the index of the current run and longest run and update them whenever you update the max value.

Also, you don't need to update the max every time you find a match just update it when the run completes.

```
int curr_index = 0, max_index = 0;
if (arr[i - 1] == arr[i]) {    
    /* the run continues */
    current++;
}
else {    
    /* the run was broken */
    if(current > max) {
        max = current;
        max_index = index;
        curr_index = i;
    } 
    current = 1;
}
```